# how to compare equals '=' in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a calculator program in javascript and HTML. I have a button with a value '=' in it.  In that one when a user click on **"="** button in calculator. it should start evaluate the input he/she had given so far. But when a user click '=' button i tried to compare like this

```
$(".calcinput").click(function () {
        var res = $(this).val();
        if (res == '=') {
            //code to handle when '=' is pressed;
        }
   }
```

but it didn't work please help me.

Comment: you dont need to check `if (res == '=')`  .. show your full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is `good` enough to handle the event .. Just add an extra `=` in comapre

```
$(".calcinput").click(function () {
    var res = $(this).val();
    //if (res == '=') {
      if (res === '=') {
        //code to handle when '=' is pressed;
    }
});
```

Next check where you used `div` or `button` or something else element to represent the `button =`

If it is `button` then use `val()` to extract the value

```
var res = $(this).val();
```

If the element is `div` then it could be `innerHTML` or `innerTEXT`

```
 var res = $(this).innerHTML;
 //Or
 var res = $(this).innerText;
```

You can add an extra line to check whether you getting proper value of `element`

```
var res = $(this).val();
alert(res);
```

Comment: Its Working Thank you

Comment: There is no jQuery `innerTEXT`or `innerHTML` property or method. Perhaps you meant *innerText*, but that isn't a jQuery method or property either, it's an IE proprietary DOM property that is not supported in all browsers. if *innerHTML* is required, then `this.innerHTML` is hugely more efficient than say `$(this).text()`.

Comment: Whether `==` or `===` is used for the comparison is irrelevant, in both cases it is comparing a string to a string so different types aren't an issue and the result will be identical.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$(this).text()
```

to retrieve button text instead of

```
$(this).val()
```

in your code

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `$(this).val()` provided you have non empty `value` attribute in the button

HTML

```
<button class ="calcinput" type ="button">1</button>
<button class ="calcinput" type ="button">2</button>
<button class ="calcinput" type ="button" value="=">=</button>
```

JS

```
$(".calcinput").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).val() === "="){
    alert("equal");
  }
})
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DHKtW/582/)

Answer (score 1):

`=` is text of button element and not value. Due to which `.val()` returns empty string. hence you need to use `.text()` instead of `.val` here:

```
$(".calcinput").click(function () {
    var res = $(this).text();
    if (res == '=') {
        //code to handle when '=' is pressed;
    }
});
```

Comment: Consider `<input type="button" value="=">`.

Comment: Given that the OP has accepted an answer full of errors, who knows what the issue was. If your answer started with "If …" it would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

check out this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/407wqm6b/)  . I have done a operation for `ADD` Simillarly you can do it for all operations ..keep it simple

```
A<input type="text" class="a" /><br/>

B<input type="text" class="b" />

<input type="button" class="calcinput" />

$(".calcinput").click(function () {
        var res1 = $(".a").val();
        var res2 = $(".b").val();
        alert(parseFloat(res1) + parseFloat(res2));
   });
```