# Javascript; Checkbox function

Tags: javascript

Below is my code, I need to use the value of the checkbox in the function and then display that in the text box. I have tried changing up the function but I just cannot get it. The formatting and everything is fine I think it has to be the syntax with the jscript. help

```js
    function getTotal(redDress, blueDress, greenDress ) {
        var redDress= 15.99 (document.getElementById("redDress").checked);
        var blueDress= 19.99 (document.getElementById("blueDress").checked);
        var greenDress= 20.99(document.getElementById("greenDress").checked);
        var subtotal= greenDress + blueDress + redDress;
        var taxAmount = .07;
        var tax = subtotal * taxAmount;
        var total = subtotal + tax;

        if((redDress=false)&&(blueDress=false)&&(greenDress=false)){
            alert("Please select a dress");
            return false && true;
        }
    }
```

```html
<form method ="get" onsubmit="return is_checked()">
        <p>Please select one or more dresses then hit submit:</p>
        <input type="checkbox" value="15.99" id="redDress">Red Dress ($15.99)   <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="19.99" id="blueDress">Blue Dress ($19.99)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="20.99" id="greenDress">Green Dress ($20.99)    <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="getTotal()"><br>
    <br>
        <br>
        Subtotal:<input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subTotal">
        <br>
        <br>
        Total:<input type="text" name="total" id="total" ><br>
        <br>
        Tax:<input type="text" name="tax" id="tax" >
        <br><br>
        This purchase was made on:
    </form>
```

Comment: what errors do you get in console? - I can tell from the distance that the syntax is not right - Related, please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question

Comment: `redDress= 15.99 (document.getElementById("redDress").checked);` no clue what you are trying to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare equals '=' in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760522/how-to-compare-equals-in-javascript)

Comment: look into a tool such as http://jshint.com/ or jslint

Comment: @epascarello i am trying to use the value of the checkbox in the function

Comment: @ochi I do not get any errors, it just does not run

Comment: Yes you do have an error message. It is `js:32 Uncaught TypeError: 15.99 is not a function` Problem you have is you have a form submission and when the error happens, the form submits...

Comment: Boooo, yes you get errors in console... if you don't know how to look for them that's fine (just say so) but the syntax is wrong (and obviously so)

Comment: @ochi well i guess I don't know how to look for it I was coding in an HTML5 file on WebStorm and no errors appeared.

Answer (score 0):

This `var redDress= 15.99 (document.getElementById("redDress").checked);` will throw an error saying `15.99` is not a function because it's the syntax of a function call (`foo (something);`). I think what you are looking for is a **ternary operator** like this:

```
var redDress= (document.getElementById("redDress").checked)? 15.99: 0;
```

which is (more or less) the same as:

```
var redDress = 0;
if(document.getElementById("redDress").checked)
    redDress = 15.99;
```

(if the user checked the `redDress` checkbox, then the value of `redDress` will be `15.99`, else it will be the default `0`).

**Note 1:** do the same for the `blueDress` and `greenDress`, and `whateverOtherDress...`.

**Note 2:** to check if the user has selected something, just check if the total `subtotal` is equal to `0` or not, like this:

```
if(subtotal == 0){
    alert("Please select a dress");
    return false; // return false , not false && trus which is the same as false
}
```

**Note 3:** No need to have those arguments if you redefine them inside the function. So this:

```
function getTotal(redDress, blueDress, greenDress ) {
    //...
```

should be just:

```
function getTotal() {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest fix would be to use ternaries for your price variables.

```
var redDress = document.getElementById("redDress").checked ? 15.99 : 0;
//if redDress is checked, redDress price = 15.99, else 0
var blueDress= document.getElementById("blueDress").checked ? 19.99 : 0;
//if blueDress is checked, blueDress price = 19.99, else 0
var greenDress= document.getElementById("greenDress").checked ? 20.99 : 0;
//if greenDress is checked, greenDress price = 20.99, else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/e4085pap/

Here it is in the context of your original code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    //listen for form submission event
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        //prevent default so form doesn't actually submit and reload the page
        event.preventDefault()
        //select all of the checkboxes and loop over them so we can determine which one is checked
        document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(input) {
            // if the input is checked then pass the cost of the dress to a function that will display the values
            if (input.checked) {
                displayValues(Number(input.value))
            }
        })
    }) 

    function displayValues(value) {
        var tax = 0.07;
        document.querySelector('input[name="subtotal"]').value = value
        document.querySelector('input[name="total"]').value = value + value * tax
        document.querySelector('input[name="tax"]').value = tax 
    }   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method ="get" onsubmit="return">
<p>Please select one or more dresses then hit submit:</p>
<input type="checkbox" value="15.99" id="redDress">Red Dress ($15.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="19.99" id="blueDress">Blue Dress ($19.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="20.99" id="greenDress">Green Dress ($20.99)    <br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
<br>
<br>
Subtotal:<input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subTotal">
<br>
<br>
Total:<input type="text" name="total" id="total" ><br>
<br>
Tax:<input type="text" name="tax" id="tax" >
<br><br>
This purchase was made on:

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way that when you click submit it has a pop up that asks for a quantity of each dress and then that factors back into the outcome in the text box?

Answer (score 0):

This update to your code will get the variables values and display the results on the text boxes, as is your original request:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">


function getTotal(redDress, blueDress, greenDress ) {

         var redDress= document.getElementById("redDress").checked ? 15.99 :0;
         var blueDress= document.getElementById("blueDress").checked ? 19.99 :0;
         var greenDress= document.getElementById("greenDress").checked ? 20.99 :0;
         var subtotal= greenDress + blueDress + redDress;
         var taxAmount = .07;
         var tax = subtotal * taxAmount;
         var total = subtotal + tax;

         if((redDress==false)&&(blueDress==false)&&(greenDress==false)){alert("Please select a dress")}

         document.getElementById('total').value = total;
         document.getElementById('subTotal').value = subtotal;
         document.getElementById('tax').value = tax;

     }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method ="get">
         <p>Please select one or more dresses then hit submit:</p>
         <input type="checkbox" value="15.99" id="redDress">Red Dress ($15.99)<br>
         <input type="checkbox" value="19.99" id="blueDress">Blue Dress ($19.99)<br>
         <input type="checkbox" value="20.99" id="greenDress">Green Dress ($20.99)    <br>
         <input type="button" value="Display" onclick="getTotal()"><br>
         <br>
         <br>
         Subtotal:<input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subTotal">
         <br>
         <br>
         Total:<input type="text" name="total" id="total"><br>
         <br>
         Tax:<input type="text" name="tax" id="tax" >
         <br><br>
         This purchase was made on:
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way that when you click submit it has a pop up that asks for a quantity of each dress and then that factors back into the outcome in the text box?

Comment: Yes @AKAceejaye, actually there is more than one way to get the desired no. of items from the user. You could have a textbox that shows right after each checkbox when checked, and the user can input how many items of each they want. Then you can get the number from the textbox element and use it as a factor on the price. You can also, as you say, pop up a smaller window on submit with inputs for the number of items, although you'll need a custom pop up for that. What you want is to have some inputs in your page to get the info you want from the user, then capture the value with JS and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Now you can get checkbox value from javascript.
code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function getTotal(redDress, blueDress, greenDress ) {
            var redDress= (document.getElementById("redDress"));
            var blueDress= (document.getElementById("blueDress"));
            var greenDress= (document.getElementById("greenDress"));
            if((redDress.checked==false)&&(blueDress.checked==false)&&(greenDress.checked==false)){
                alert("Please select a dress");
            }
            if(redDress.checked==true)
                console.log(redDress.value);
            if(blueDress.checked==true)
                console.log(blueDress.value);
            if(greenDress.checked==true)
                console.log(greenDress.value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method ="get" onsubmit="return is_checked()">
        <p>Please select one or more dresses then hit submit:</p>
        <input type="checkbox" value="15.99" id="redDress">Red Dress ($15.99)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="19.99" id="blueDress">Blue Dress ($19.99)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="20.99" id="greenDress">Green Dress ($20.99)    <br>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="getTotal()"><br>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way that when you click submit it has a pop up that asks for a quantity of each dress and then that factors back into the outcome in the text box?